# How to get the fn keys to work after replacing a Inspiron 1545 (laptop) keyboard with a 1525 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

My Inspiron 1545 keyboard has failed but I have a 1525 keyboard leftover that works. My problem is that the "Fn" keys differ significantly, would someone be as so kind to help me reassign those keys?

It would so greatly be appreciated. The 1525 & 1545's model #'s are BA86 & A198, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If they're the same size, pop the keys and swap em. I would've suggested AutoHotKey but it doesn't do too well with Fn keys